# Regular expression replacement does not work with capturing group

Tags: texmaker, regular-expressions

This post is about TeXMaker.

I tried to use regular expression replacement with the last TexMaker version on Windows.

Expressions to replace:

```
\textbf{foo}
\textbf{bar}
```

Regexp to match: `\\textbf\{([a-zA-Z]*)\}`
to replace with: `\textit{$1}`

Gives:

```
\textit{\textbf{foo}}
\textit{\textbf{bar}}
```

Do I do something wrong? Or did I misunderstand the [manual](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/texmaker_v5.0.2/share/texmaker/usermanual_en.html#SECTION43) ?

#### EDIT to answer comments:

With replacement expression as: `\textit{$2}`
It gives:

```
\textit{$2}
\textit{$2}
```

I also tried `$0` to check if its an issue related to groups identifier, but it does not work either.

Comment: are you sure you haven't got an outer set of (...) ?

Comment: you could try with `$2` in case `$1` means the whole match.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I am.

Comment: The manual actually suggests `([^}]*)` i.e. a class consisting of any character not a closing brace. That said, I have run into issues with greediness in the past: perhaps using a quantifier such as `+` (one or more times) instead of `*` (zero or more times) helps?

Answer (score 1):

I get in touch with the TexMaker creator, he said that its a bug that will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/235003)

Comment: I suggest to Edit your initial question, update there with this info, and delete this remark.

Comment: @MS-SPO this is a valid answer (question: how to use regex? answer: you can't, it is a bug). See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7008/89417 for an answer by moderator Joseph Wright in a related discussion.

Comment: Ok, you can view it that way. Problem is: somebody flagged it as a low-quality answer. Well, counting characters, it is, watching it in context, it's fine. Make your choice :)